# Ionic framework: Structuring custom service providers

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, directory-structure

I've been doing tons of research to find out what's the wise way to structure Ionic project. Currently, I'm focusing on [Building A Serverless API using Firebase Cloud Functions](https://codeburst.io/building-a-serverless-api-using-firebase-cloud-functions-e5a6be42144c)

One thing that came up to my mind was the following command below seems to make a structure of service providers unsustainable. *(Maybe I'm wrong)*

```
$ ionic generate provider provider-name

- Project Root
  - src
     - providers
        - user-service.ts
        - auth-service.ts
        - some other services
```

I'd like to create a custom service directory something looks like this

```
- Project Root
  - src
     - common
        - http
           - rest-service.ts // abstract class
           - providers
              - local-storage-service.ts
              - notification-service.ts
     - providers
        - user-service.ts
        - auth-service.ts
        - some other services
```

Is this the right approach to do so? I'm not sure what's the best practice for organizing the project structure efficiently to make them maintainable for long-term use. Any ideas?

Comment: It's up to you. If you need to provide extensive structure for common providers, this possibly means that you've accumulated too much instead of making them reusable modules.

Comment: Thank you for the response, @estus Hmm... What I'm trying to do is place the simple HTTP service logic inside a base class `(rest-service.ts)` and derive API services from it.

Comment: I guess `http` is a good candidate for making it a separate repo with NgModule module.

Comment: @estus Could you provide some example code for better understanding?

Comment: Check any third-party Angular module on npm. The point is that you don't need to host all reusable things in project folder.

Comment: Alright. Thanks estus.